# How can I combine pandas' .explode() with a .split() on multiple columns with a single additional row

Tags: python, pandas

I want to re-arrange a Pandas Dataframe to include an extra row based on the values in two (or more) columns whenever they include a delimiter. This extra row would have all variables identical to the original, except for the columns which are searched for a delimiter. If a delimiter is found, I would want an additional row with the second elements of both columns (after the delimiter).  The following code works for a single column and illustrates my goals nicely:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([{'var1': 'a,b,c', 'var2': 1}, {'var1': 'd,e,f', 'var2': 2}])

df.assign(var1=df.var1.str.split(',')).explode('var1').reset_index(drop=True)
```

Although when specifying two columns, multiple rows are included for each column, as the following code yields:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([{'var1': 'a,b,c', 'var2': 1, 'var3': 'I, II, III'}, {'var1': 'd,e,f', 'var2': 2, 'var3': 'IV, V, VI'}])

df.assign(var1=df.var1.str.split(','), var2=df.var2.str.split(',')).explode('var1').explode('var2').reset_index(drop=True)
```

I would like to have a single row included with the second element of both columns, like so:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([{'var1': 'a', 'var2': 1, 'var3': 'I'}, {'var1': 'b', 'var2': 1, 'var3': 'II'}, {'var1': 'c', 'var2': 1, 'var3': 'III'}, {'var1': 'd', 'var2': 2, 'var3': 'IV'}, {'var1': 'e', 'var2': 2, 'var3': 'V'}, {'var1': 'f', 'var2': 2, 'var3': 'VI'}])
```

I know that splitting and exploding on both columns and then subsetting the resultant dataframe would allow me to obtain the result I want, but I was looking for a potentially cleaner way to do this.

Note that for each rows, both delimiter columns will always have the same amount of delimiters.

**edit**

The .explode() attribute is only available in pandas >= 0.25.x

Comment: So the last DataFrame is your expected output?

Comment: correct! that was the dataframe I was looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, if I understand correctly, it is better to explicitly explode rather than use `.explode` method (which is how it was done for pandas < 0.25.1). [From `method #2` of this thread,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53218931/how-to-unnest-explode-a-column-in-a-pandas-dataframe) you may

```
df.var1 = df.var1.str.split(',')
df.var3 = df.var3.str.split(',')

pd.DataFrame({'var1': np.concatenate(df.var1.values),
              'var2': df.var2.repeat(df.var1.str.len()), 
              'var3': np.concatenate(df.var3.values)})
```

---

```
  var1  var2  var3
0    a     1     I
0    b     1    II
0    c     1   III
1    d     2    IV
1    e     2     V
1    f     2    VI
```

Comment: This seems to throw a ValueError for me in the np.concatenate() call for 'var1': ValueError: zero-dimensional arrays cannot be concatenated. Same issue for the second np.concatenate() call.

Comment: @MarkVerhagen sorry, forgot to add the splits! Updated

Comment: Thanks @rafaelc! Works fabulously.